# Arduino loop does not stop - only with smaller counters. Arduino Nano Every

Tags: c++, automation, arduino, relayjs

I cannot explain to myself why this code works properly  in some cases and in some not. Here is the situation:

I am trying to switch a relay with the Arduino Nano. Therefore I took the "Blink" example as a guide. It should switch on for like 5 minutes and switch off for like 25 minutes. Here is the code:

```
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);               // sets PIN 2 as switcher for the relay
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  int count = 0;
  int run_pump = 300;               // 5 Min run
  int stop_pump = 1500;             // 25 Min stop
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // turn the LED off (HIGH is the voltage level)
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);            // turn the pump on
  while(count < run_pump) {
    count++;
    delay(1000);                    // wait for a second
  }
  
  count = 0;              
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);             // turn the pump off
  while(count < stop_pump) {
    count++;
    delay(1000);                    // wait for a second
  }
}
```

if I run this code on the Arduino it will just switch on the relay forever. BUT: If I set `run_pump` and `stop_pump` for like 10 sec. it will work properly! Is there an explanation why this does not work with the bigger counters? It's so confusing....

so this code here works absolutely fine, but why does the code above not?

```
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);               // sets PIN 2 as switcher for the relay
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  int count = 0;
  int run_pump = 5;               // 5 sec run
  int stop_pump = 10;             // 10 sec stop
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // turn the LED off (HIGH is the voltage level)
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);            // turn the pump on
  while(count < run_pump) {
    count++;
    delay(1000);                    // wait for a second
  }
  
  count = 0;              
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);             // turn the pump off
  while(count < stop_pump) {
    count++;
    delay(1000);                    // wait for a second
  }
}
```

Hope someone has a clue.... Thanks!
Tom

Comment: absolute the same thing with a for loop... small counters work.

Comment: This maybe some hardware issue. Check if you can control LED instead of relay. Disconnect relay from the board entirely for that test just to make sure that it will not interfere.

Comment: If it's a hardware issue then check the power supply. If you are powering your relay from arduino board it might overload the voltage regulator and after a while voltage drops and you are getting a reset. And if your board resets after a few seconds of pump being on then it would appear as if the loop was stuck. Also make sure that you are not running you relay directly from the IO pin. You need a transistor (and diod to supress voltage spikes) for that.

Comment: Hey @Bill2462, thanks for your ideas! I checked it and it worked properly. This led to the thought it could be any other hardware part, like the relay. The relay was a cheap one with chinese letters on it and that was the source of evil! Don't  know why, but it talked to the Ardunino saying "I do what I want after 10 seconds!". I replaced it :) Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I solved it. The problem was a cheap relay that was trying to communicate with the Arduino... Replacing it with a better one solved the whole problem. Thanks for the idea with the LED, this brought some stones to roll... :)